# move large register into small memory

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have a little problem understanding PTR Operator, I can easily move large memory into small register example below:

```
ax = small register which is 2 byte
memory = variable which is 4 byte


.data
variable dword 05010h

.code
mov ax,WORD PTR variable
```

It will works fine.
Now my problem is I don't understand why I can't move large register like `eax` into a small memory variable which is 2 byte?

Example:

```
.data
variable word ?

.code

mov eax, 01050h
mov variable, word ptr eax
```

It's says: `Error invalid use of register`

Note: it works fine if the size is match

Comment: Can you tell the difference between `mov word ptr variable, eax` and `mov variable, word ptr eax` or was that a typo?

Comment: Error: instruction operands must be the same size

Comment: `mov ax,WORD PTR variable` is loading the first 2 bytes of the variable, not the whole variable.  If you want to store the first 2 bytes of `eax`, you have to use `ax` as the source operand.  Thus  you'd use `mov WORD PTR variable, ax`.  The `word ptr` has to go on the memory operand, and it has to match the register.  It's only needed at all because labels in MASM magically get a size associated based on what data you put right after them.

Comment: Yes i know that well, I just want to know why I can't mov any byte of large register into small memory

Comment: you can do `mov dword ptr [variable], eax` (overwriting 4 bytes of course, i.e. 2B beyond reserved variable "word"). Or if you want to store only low 16 bits of `eax`, you can do `mov [variable], ax`, as `eax` has "alias" register `ax` for lower 16 bits. (to store upper 16 bits you have to either extract them, for example `shr eax,16` to move those into `ax`, or store `dword` into memory and then operate with the last 2B only to have upper 16b data).

Comment: (Almost) all x86 instructions other than `movzx` / `movsx` require all/both operands to be the same size.  When you `mov ax,WORD PTR variable`, you're overriding the size of `variable` to 16 bits.  The CPU doesn't know or care that it was a 4-byte "variable", it's just a 2-byte load because that's what you asked for.  For a store, the only way to write it is to use a 16-bit register to go with the 16-bit destination.

Comment: Well, yes, the whole "variable" terminology is a bit misleading in assembly, as you have memory, addressable by bytes, and that's it, so you have either some value (in amount of bits you desire, but 8/16/32/64 are natively supported by modern x86 CPU), or you have memory address (pointing to some particular byte in the memory chip). The "variable" is unknown concept to CPU, and most of the assemblers provide like anti-variable philosophy to keep in the same spirit as HW CPU is designed, MASM is one of the few to try to be a bit "smart" about declarations, often just getting into my way.. :D

Comment: thanks guys for replies, I got it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are obviously not aware what the following instruction does:

```
mov ax, word ptr variable
```

This instruction does **not** read the 32-bit variable and write the variable to a 16-bit register!

But what does it do?

In general the CPU does not know which data type is stored in a certain memory location. Memory at the address `variable` may contain the following bytes:

```
01h 02h 03h 04h
```

This can be four 8-bit variables, two 16-bit variables (with the values 201h and 403h), one 32-bit variable with the value 4030201h or even one 16-bit and two 8-bit variables.

Because the CPU does not know which kind of variables is stored in the memory it is **up to the programmer** (or the compiler) to write an assembler program in a way that a 16-bit variable is accessed as 16-bit variable.

The instruction `mov ax, variable` means: "There is a 16-bit variable in the RAM at the location (address) `variable`. Read it and write it into the `ax` register."

The CPU will do this. Because the memory contains the bytes `01h 02h 03h 04h` in our example it will read the two bytes `01h 02h` and interpret them as 16-bit variable (having the value 201h).

Using so-called "little-endian" CPUs (like x86) this will result in the "correct" value when the 32-bit variable has a "small" value because the instruction will effectively read the low 16 bits of the 32-bit variable.

By the way: Using "big-endian" CPUs (like PowerPC) even this would not work any more because the high (and not the low) 16 bits of the 32-bit variable would be read.

Of course you could also read a memory location containing a 16-bit variable into a 32-bit register:

```
mov eax, variable
```

Let's say in the example above `01h 02h 03h 04h` are two 16-bit variables having the values 201h and 403h. If you read this RAM memory as 32-bit value you'll get 4030201h as result, not 201h!

x86 CPUs (since the 80386) have two instructions `movsx` (sign-extend high bits) and `movzx` (set high bits to zero) which are used to copy a smaller value into a larger register.

These instructions allow you to "correctly" read a 16-bit value into a 32-bit register.

**EDIT**

According to Peter Cordes MASM explicitly requires a `dword ptr` in `mov eax, dword ptr variable` because MASM will otherwise check if `variable` is really 32-bit and print an error message.

For the CPU the instructions `mov eax, variable` and `mov eax, dword ptr variable` are however exactly the same instruction.

> ```
> mov variable, word ptr eax
> ```
>
> It's says: `Error invalid use of register`

The instruction would probably (I'm not sure as I don't use MASM) be named:

```
mov dword ptr variable, eax
```

However you should be aware what this instruction will do: It will overwrite 32 bits in memory: The `variable` and the data which is following `variable` in memory. I doubt that this is what you really want to do.

If you want to "convert" a 32-bit value into a 16-bit value like the following C code:

```
variable16 = (unsigned short)variable32;
```

... the following assembler code will do the job:

```
mov eax, variable32
mov variable16, ax
```

... because `ax` is the low 16 bits of `eax`.

Comment: The OP is using MASM, so the `word ptr` override is not optional.  `variable dword 05010h` means that `variable` by itself implies dword operand size.  Unlike in NASM, where `[variable]` has no implied size, so you can tell what a source line assembles to just by looking at it without also looking elsewhere.